# Perl - string matching issue

Tags: regex, perl

I have a problem I cannot understand. I have this string:

```
gene_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543"transcript_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543_X_1";tss_id "TSS124620"
```

And I want to change the gene_id. So, I have the following code:

```
if ($line =~ /;transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*)(_[oxOX][_.][0-9]*)";/) {
    $num = $2;
    $line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*)";/gene_id "$1$num";/g;
    print $new $line."\n";
}
```

The aim of my code is to change `siRNA_Z27kG1_20543` for `siRNA_Z27kG1_20543_X_1`. However, my code does not produce that output. Why? I can't understand that.

My regex needs to be as it is because I match other strings (this time with success).

Comment: `if ($line =~ s/gene_id \K".+?"(?=transcript_id "(.+?)")/"$1"/) {..}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon at the start of the pattern as it is not present in the string :-

```
if ($line =~ /transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*)(_[oxOX][_.][0-9]*)";/) {
            $num = $2;
            $line =~ s/gene_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*)";/gene_id "$1$num";/g;
            print $new $line."\n";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = q{gene_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543"transcript_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543_X_1";tss_id "TSS124620"};
if($string =~ m|transcript_id "([A-Za-z0-9:\-._]*)(_[oxOX][_.][0-9]*)"|){
    my $replace_with = qq{gene_id "$1$2"};
    $string =~ s/gene_id (\"\w+\")/$replace_with/g;
}
print "$string";
```

Output: `gene_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543_X_1"transcript_id "siRNA_Z27kG1_20543_X_1";tss_id "TSS124620"`

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/zrSNC2)